# Can a result be statistically significant if the null value is one of the 95% confidence intervals?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value

I'm reading a paper on the effect of 2 different drugs on mortality. The results are reported as RR 0.96 (0.94-1.00), p=0.03. The p value indicates significance but the upper 95% limit is 1.00.

Am I mistaken in thinking that this doesn't make sense? These confidence intervals suggest there is a 95% confidence that the true effect could be 1.00 (i.e., no effect at all). The've not reported this as a rounding error but I suppose it could be? Am I misunderstanding something about what confidence intervals mean?

Comment: yes it's rounding

Comment: It's likely rounding as others said, but something interesting to think about is if it really makes a difference relative to interpreting the results - e.g., Is p=0.03 strong enough evidence against the null?

Answer (score 0):

While this is most likely just due to rounding, there are different methods of calculating confidence intervals for parameter estimates that will give similar, but still different, values and may not both correspond to the p-value significance.

For example in logistic regression, one could calculate Wald confidence intervals or profile likelihood-based confidence intervals estimates.